# How to get timepicker / datepicker dialogFragment cancel button event

Tags: android-dialogfragment, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

I used the android developers time picker & date picker 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html
and I want when the user clicks cancel button in the dialog to do some actions
I tied ondismiss, onStop, onCancel
But no luck can  you tell me the simple method to catch this event ??

thnx all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used boolean to check if the time/data is set or not